# to ensure that physically corrupt data is not read

Tags: database-design

Can you please explain what they mean by 'physically corrupt data'?

> Read uncommitted (the lowest level where transactions are isolated
> only enough to ensure that physically corrupt data is not read)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189122(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that *physically corrupt data* means that whatever physical container holds the data - typically *blocks* or *pages* - always deliver a sound and well formatted structure, no matter what failures happen.

The lowest storage unit of a relational database is traditionally called a *page* or a *block*. A page is usually formed by multiple disk I/O units (disk blocks or sectors). The I/O subsystem guarantees that a sector is always written as an atomic I/O unit: it either succeeds or fails.

However, if (as is pretty much always the case) a page is formed by multiple sectors, then changes to that page need to be written in multiple sectors, as a consistent unit: either **all** sectors are written - or **none** is written. The OS I/O subsystem does not automatically guarantee that:
the lower level of the RDBMS (the I/O manager generally) must guarantee that instead.

This is what that sentence means: even when I use the *read uncommitted* isolation level, there is still a minimal consistency level that guarantees that the physical storage units of the database (the pages) are always consistent at the physical level.

Comment: I'm confused - doesn't the OS sit on top of hardware and then software (e.g. an RDBMS) then sits on top of that?